# Multiple markers on one location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have the following problem: I have three google map markers which point to the same location, and I need to show all of them and their infowindows, not just one. I have seen examples where a marker branches out on click, showing multiple infowindows on the same location, but I can't find code for it. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Maybe this could help you:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15436/google-markers-at-same-address-not-showing-all-markers

Hope this helps.

Comment: This https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/blob/master/README.textile sounds like what you are talking about, with demo here http://jawj.github.com/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html I don't like it because when a marker is clicked the expansion collapses, so it's not easy to navigate the infowindows. :( I don't feel capable of hacking the source

Comment: You can avoid the collapse effect of spider if you use `keepSpiderfied: true` e.g. `var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, {keepSpiderfied: true});`